# How to execute h:commandButton actionListener before onclick?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I need some help in the below code

```
                <h:commandButton  id="WhatifButtonID" value="#{demandBean.dmdReviewScreenLabelVO.whatIf}" style="width:60px; height:22px;"  actionListener="#{demandBean.whatif}"  onclick="window.open('DemandTargetList.xhtml','whatif','width=460,height=280,top=150,left=350,resizable=no,scrollbars=no')" >
                    <f:ajax execute="@this" ></f:ajax>
                </h:commandButton>
```

In the above case, the onclick attribute gets executed first followed by the actionlistener attribute. I wanted the actionListener attribute to get executed first followed by the onclick function, since the page that loads onclick needs to get certain values from the actionListener.  Please let me know how to acheive the same. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just let `<f:ajax>` render a script on complete.

```
<h:commandButton value="#{demandBean.dmdReviewScreenLabelVO.whatIf}" actionListener="#{demandBean.whatif}">
    <f:ajax execute="@this" render="popupScript" />
</h:commandButton>
<h:panelGroup id="popupScript">
    <h:outputScript rendered="#{demandBean.whatifPressed}">
        window.open('DemandTargetList.xhtml','whatif','width=460,height=280,top=150,left=350,resizable=no,scrollbars=no');
    </h:outputScript>
</h:panelGroup>
```

wherein you set `whatifPressed` to `true` in the `whatif()` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot BalusC for such a quick response. It really helped. But the time taken to load the popup seems to be a bitmore. Also can you please let me know the order in which the attributes are getting executed. How do I get to know which attribute gets executed first.

Comment: It's easy if you understand how HTML/JS works (as that's basically all which JSF generates). So going through a decent HTML/JS tutorial and then looking at the JSF-generated HTML/JS code (rightclick page in browser and do *View Source*) should be clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

PrimeFaces may help with this with the use of the `<p:remoteCommand/>` tag.  You can then just use a plain old button to call the remoteCommand, then simply execute the window.open().

```
<p:remoteCommand name="viewSomething" actionListener="#{someActionIWantToExecuteBeforeOpeningWindow}" update="@this" process="@this"/>
<button onclick="viewSomething(); window.open('http://somewhere.com', 'windowName', 'height=924,width=723');">Click me!</button>
```

You can use it over lists of items if you call the javascript function it creates something unique.